# Different Results under Inverse Laplace Transform

Tags: integral-transforms

I am getting different results from the following commands:

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[a/Sqrt[(a*u)+(a*u)^2 ],u,t]

InverseLaplaceTransform[a/Sqrt[(a u)* (1 + a u)], u, t]
```

In the first one, i have $\frac{1}{a}$ multiplicative factor that doesn't appear on the second one. Any ideas?

Comment: Examine the `FullForm`s of the input expressions and apply `FullSimplify` on both of them and examine the output

Comment: Can you show us what the output is? It might vary between versions.

Comment: Using the FullForm and FullSimplify i get same result.

Comment: Theoutput are:
 
Exp[-t/2a]BesselI[0,t/2]/a on the first one 

and

Exp[-t/2a]BesselI[0,t/2] on the second one


I'm using Mathematica 10.1 Student Edition